# Hive - error while copying data into table

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I am getting the below error while copying data into hive table - I have given g+w permissions to user/hive/warehouse and /tmp.

Failed with exception Unable to move source file:/home/vm4learning/Desktop/vehicletesting.txt to destination hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/imdb.db/vts/vehicletesting.txt
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask

Answer (score 0):

but you're trying to copy to
   hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/imdb.db/vts
so you should check that directory's permissions.

Comment: they both are same - just that hdfs://localhost .... is the total description. I have also check permission to both of them is same

Comment: how about the source file ? Hive tries to _move_ it, not copy it, so the source file should be writable too.